Working Around or Resolving Recurring Distortions From Microphone/ADC
I've got a microphone being piped through a USB ADC and there's a recurrent loud distortion which occurs exactly every 15 seconds -- sounding a bit like a clip or click. I have confirmed that it is bad input and not any software on my computer causing the problem, and that the Microphone itself does not produce the artefacts.

Whilst I can manually cut these out (being only .02 seconds in length) they are rather annoying and the process gets rather tedious for long recordings.
Is there a decent way to cut out regular intervals from the input stream or otherwise automate the removal of these artefacts?
I don't presently have the facilities to replace the ADC but in the event these are irredeemable problems I can attempt to use another to test.

Actually the most likely cause of this is sample rate mismatch between the interface and the recording software.

@ToddWilcox I thought so but the interval and artefacting is entirely unaffected by changing the recording sampling rate
